# Is it possible to include script tags inside a PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP file which deals with registration on a site, currently once the user has registered they are redirected to the home page and a success message states that the user's registration has been successful.

I would like to change this to a jquery notification.

Is it possible for me to include jquery within this registration PHP file?

For example.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_v_1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_notification_v.1.js"></script>
```

If I place this at the top of the page before the PHP tags commence.

If this is not possible, what is the best way to overcome this obstacle?

Thank you

Comment: php knows nothing about javascript and jquery

Comment: best way around what?

Comment: you can include script tags/html/css into php files and they'll be printed as is. @zerkms he is not talking about php as a scripting language but a php file.

Comment: @Pixulated, PHP runs first on the server (server-side) and after PHP is done running, the end result is the HTML webpage you are seeing. After the page is fully loaded on the client machine, then javascript can run. So you can never mix the two together. Read some basic books on PHP/MySQL/Javascript to get a better understanding. Think of PHP as the cake and javascript as the icing. You can't add the icing before the cake comes out of the oven :)

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut: I don't see your point. php doesn't care what it outputs. It's just a bunch of bytes for it, nothing more

Comment: Hm... i am afraid that OP should reformulate question...

Comment: @zerkms you are still referring "php" as a scripting language. "php file" cares about what it outputs.

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut: I'm not sure what "php file cares" means. File cannot care of anything, it's a file. PHP programming language doesn't care of actual output it produces.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: you are the one using "care" and humanizing entities. programming language doesn't care too, not yet anyway. they just do what they are told to do. but that is not the issue here. the vagualy asked question is, if i include javascript files into my php file, would it work. and the answer is YES. wether php *knows* or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut: it is relevant. The point is that php doesn't care if what to be output is javascript, html or some other thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is fine, as long as they are outside of the `<?php ?>` tags

Comment: Of course, using  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js></script>'"    is also possible.

Comment: but this is a string and not a tag

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. just be careful not to put any javascript/html (any output, not even space) code *before* `header` or `session_start` functions, cause these will cause problems if anything is printed before they run.

Comment: "not to put any javascript/html code" --- that's why generalization is good. The correct would be: "don't put **any output**", otherwise you're confusing newbies even more.